# Cell range for COUNTIF criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sets of strings, let's say `A1` to `A5`, and `A10` to `A20`.

I understand that `COUNTIF(range, criteria)` will give me the number of cells in `range` that match `criteria`.

I'd like to extend this so `criteria` can be a range, too.

So—in effect—I'd like to check if any cell in the range `criteria` matches any cell in the range `range`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula in google-speadsheets:

```
=sum(arrayformula(COUNTIF(A1:A3,B1:B3)))
```